# In MySQL it is possible to use a procedure to include resultset of a query into another?

Tags: mysql, json, stored-procedures, relational-database

I have two tables according the following scheme

**contact**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mark |
| 2 | Matthew |
| 3 | Luke |
| 4 | John |

**contact_relation**

| contact_id | related_contact_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | reference |
| 1 | 2 | association |
| 1 | 3 | association |
| 2 | 3 | reference |
| 3 | 4 | association |

I need to get a resultset like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Mark",
        "references": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Matthew"
            }
        ],
        "associations": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Matthew"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Luke"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Matthew",
        "references": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Luke"
            }
        ],
        "associations": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Luke",
        "references": [],
        "associations": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "John"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I wrote the code with PHP and it works fine if there are few contacts. But the full list has over 31,000 contacts with a response time of over 20 minutes.

Is it possible to write a mysql procedure (or whatever) that allows me to have the same result? Even if the indexes *references* and *associations* cannot be JSON but JSON in string format, that's fine.

Thanks for support

**MySQL Scripts** (as generated in MySQL Workbench)

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`contact`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`contact` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` TINYTEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`contact_relation`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`contact_relation` (
  `contact_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `related_contact_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `type` TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
  INDEX `fk_contact_relation_contact_idx` (`contact_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_contact_relation_contact1_idx` (`related_contact_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_contact_relation_contact`
    FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`contact` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_contact_relation_contact1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`related_contact_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`contact` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `mydb`.`contact`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `mydb`;
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`contact` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'Mark');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`contact` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (2, 'Matthew');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`contact` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (3, 'Luke');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`contact` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (4, 'John');

COMMIT;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `mydb`.`contact_relation`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `mydb`;
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`contact_relation` (`contact_id`, `related_contact_id`, `type`) VALUES (1, 2, 'reference');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`contact_relation` (`contact_id`, `related_contact_id`, `type`) VALUES (1, 2, 'association');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`contact_relation` (`contact_id`, `related_contact_id`, `type`) VALUES (1, 3, 'association');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`contact_relation` (`contact_id`, `related_contact_id`, `type`) VALUES (2, 3, 'reference');
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`contact_relation` (`contact_id`, `related_contact_id`, `type`) VALUES (3, 4, 'association');

COMMIT;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: *Is it possible to write a mysql procedure (or whatever) that allows me to have the same result?* Of course. Moreover, SP not needed, everything may be performed in one query. *I have two tables according the following scheme* Provide CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, not (only) table-like form. Ensure the desired output **strictly** matches provided source data. Specify **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: Thanks @Akina I added the script for MySQL queries – Luca Romano 56 mins ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT cr.contact_id, 
                 cr.related_contact_id,
                 cr.type, 
                 JSON_OBJECT('id', c.id, 'name', c.name) rel_obj
          FROM contact_relation cr
          JOIN contact c ON cr.related_contact_id = c.id ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT type
          FROM contact_relation ),
cte3 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT contact_id
          FROM contact_relation ),
cte4 AS ( SELECT type, 
                 contact_id,
                 contact.name,
                 JSON_ARRAYAGG(rel_obj) rel_obj
          FROM cte2
          CROSS JOIN cte3
          NATURAL LEFT JOIN cte1
          JOIN contact ON cte3.contact_id = contact.id
          GROUP BY type, 
                   contact_id,
                   contact.name ),
cte5 AS ( SELECT contact_id id,
                 name,
                 MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'reference' THEN rel_obj END) reference,
                 MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'association' THEN rel_obj END) association
          FROM cte4
          GROUP BY contact_id,
                   name )
SELECT REPLACE(JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', id, 
                                         'name', name,
                                         'references', reference,
                                         'associations', association)), '[null]', '[]' )output
FROM cte5;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=748c70678b4f7a17b468ebacb096ebdc

Comment: Thank you so much @Akina. Do you know if there is a way to do it even in MySQL 5.7?

Comment: `WITH cte AS (SELECT ..) SELECT ... FROM ... cte ...` simply converted to `SELECT .. FROM .. (SELECT ..) AS cte ..` which is applicable in 5.7

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6be2439a35c7e0c9d83e9e79a45bc7ec

Comment: Thank you @Akina, but in MySQL 5.7 there is a problem: *references* and *associations* have the same values ad inside of them there are duplicates.

Comment: @LucaRomano Maybe I was inaccurate during replacing... do the same with accuracy.

Comment: I tried many times to rewrite from 8.0 to 5.7, but results are still duplicates. I tried to group even for cte2.type that cte3.type but it doesn't resolve the duplicate. Maybe it is and error of MySQL 5.7 that doesn't work as expected. The problem seems to be *CROSS JOIN*, if I remove it works, even if add double quote before [. This is the link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2c2594e18af905fa8c0559b3491aed2e